# Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0010: No available device

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

Whenever I try to start the HelloMaui project from VS Code using NET 6.0.100 Preview4 with mono debug extension installed and run it it throws an error Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(604,5): error XA0010: No available device. I wonder if anyone had a problem running the sample project?

Answer (score 1):

The same bug has been reported 3 days ago in the official repo https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1197, as MAUI still in an early stage it better to follow on the official repo.

Try to ensure that the emulator is ready before debugging the app (build+deploy), by starting it manually.

Not sure how to do it from vs code but probably will be common for command line:

1. Navigate to `C:\*\Android\android-sdk\emulator`
2. `emulator -list-avds`
   You should see at least one emulator name otherwise you need to install one.
3. `emulator.exe -avd NameOfYourEmulator -partition-size 512` NameOfYourEmulator taken from the previous step.

#### Docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/command-line-emulator

#### Edit

If the returned list of Android device emulators is empty (from step 2) and you are sure you have at least one emulator previously added/installed then try [unloading and reloading the android project](https://github.com/dotnet/maui#running).

If you are not sure, you may open Android device manager from visual studio and check the listed devices there, if empty then you need to add at least one.

Related issue [Maui-check fails on Android Emulator Setup](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/issues/155)

Comment: I tried running the command  for listing the avds but none shows up... and maui check suposedly didnt find any but there were some installed by visual studio when running xamarin how could I use those? @Cfun

Comment: if you open Android device manager from visual studio,is there any emulator listed or no? if no and you are sure you have at least one emulator previously added then try [unloading and reloading the android project](https://github.com/dotnet/maui#running)